# How to send Push notification to a particular user using GCM

Tags: android, asp.net, google-cloud-messaging

I have created an application which is fetching data from server and displaying the data to a particular user. Now I want that if any record is inserted in the database which is on the server the particular user get the push notification from the server.

Comment: Can't you create a trigger on server in database? Any new record inserted, it will fire a trigger and code for push notification will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this link to implement GCM for your android powered device.

[Android GCM Push Notification Demo](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Also you need to implement a server side implementation to configure you server with GCM compatible.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks but i want to use dot net instead of php. can u help me